# Why doesn't removeAccessToken in JdbcTokenStore return feedback?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm using JdbcTokenStore, and someone complained that when they remove a token that wasn't stored (and thus invalid) they don't get any feedback that says that this token was invalid anyway. I could add a check to see if the token was stored and only then remove it, but I thought maybe there was a reason the JdbcTokenStore doesn't give you this information when you remove a token.

So, why doesn't the function removeAccessToken in JdbcTokenStore return whether the token was valid or not? Is it some general principle, a technical thing or something else?

Answer (score 0):

According to me, implementation of revoke access token is done in such way to make it abstract and allow developers to make their custom implementation as and whenever required. 
Like we had the requirement to logout the android client and invalidate and remove the access token.
 So we mapped the logout handler to a url like :

```
<http pattern="/rs/**" create-session="never" request-matcher="ant" use-expressions="true"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="oauthAuthenticationManager"
        access-decision-manager-ref="oauthAccessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/rs/logout" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"  method="GET" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/rs/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
    </http>
    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="com.oauth.web.security.OAuthLogoutHandler">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    </bean>
```

In OAuthLogoutHandler we removed the access and refresh token as:

```
public class OAuthLogoutHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {
    private JdbcTokenStore      tokenStore;

@Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authorizationHeader != null) {
            int indexOfSeparator = authorizationHeader.indexOf(tokenSeparator);
            if (indexOfSeparator > -1) {
                String tokenValue = authorizationHeader.substring(indexOfSeparator).trim();
                if (tokenValue != null && !tokenValue.isEmpty()) {
                    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
                    if (accessToken != null) {
                        tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(accessToken.getRefreshToken());
                        tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
                        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
                        response.setHeader("responseCode", "success");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    }
```